# APNS notification does not work when app is not running or background

Tags: iphone, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I'm using pyapns to send notification to iPhone.

receiving notification when the app is running was success.

but, when app is not running or app is on background, it can't receive notification.

is it related with URL identifier or scheme? if not, what is the problem..?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get called in

```
- (void)application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
```

while you were in the app?

Comment: Can you please tell me how you maintain the connection with your server. How you giving the device token to the server? may be you are unregistering for remote notification when you entering the app background or app exit or may be because calling the push log to server with no device token. Please check for these criteria first.

Comment: I received device token using didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken function.
and I sent notification using pyapns protocol (notify function) with correct device token. so that I could receive message from server with didReceiveRemoteNotification function when the app is running.
 but, I can't understand why it can't receive the message or doesn't call didReceiveRemoteNotification when the app is on background or not running.

Comment: did you check that? is that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the problem from notification msg.

among the notify function args, there is notifications list arg.

note that, when you make this parameter, a dictionary of this list should contain below. so that the application can do alert reaction.

```
thePayLoad = {
     'aps': {
          'alert':'this option should be contained if you want to see the alert msg',
          'sound':'k1DiveAlarm.caf',
          'badge':42
      },
     'test_data': { 'foo': 'bar' }
}
```

In my case, I just sent msg not containing above. and in didReceiveRemoteNotification function, I made alert msg. but msg not containing alert information. so the device couldn't react.